# Incomplete MaxSAT in z3

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, sat

I have a problem where I am considering to use incomplete MaxSAT algorithms. Are there any incomplete MaxSMT solvers implemented in z3?

Comment: I doubt z3 has any. @PatrickTrentin might know. If not, ask at the z3 discussions page: github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions